# Send Post request using OKHttp library from android to php file on localhost

Tags: php, android

I made an android app that gets user location and send this data to php file on localhost using OKHttp library the main problem that the response is always null from localhost as app can't connect to it while changing to other urls response status code is 200 how can I adjust the url so it would connect on localhost.

```
    String result, codeStatus;
    ResponseBody resbody;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... locationData) {
        ArrayList<String> passed = locationData[0];
        String lat = passed.get(0);
        String longt = passed.get(1);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("latitude", lat)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://127.0.0.1/test.php")
                .method("POST", body)
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            resbody = response.body();
            result = response.body().string();
            int code = response.code();
            codeStatus = String.valueOf(code);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            resbody.close();
        }

        return codeStatus;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        showData.setText(response);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "result " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is loopback address and the Android device itself. You should use the ip of your pc instead.

Comment: I already used the ip of the pc and doesn't work too.

Comment: Then why didnt you tell? Well that should work. And if you do not tell the errors/ cexceptions you get then what is it that you want us to do for you?

Comment: `that the response is always null ` Pretty unclueas what you mean by that. Please give better info.

Comment: I don't know which part is unclear I said that my only problem is with my localhost ip http://192.x.x.x/test.php the response comes from okhttp is null and sometimes my app crashes but when I put another url as http://www.google.com.eg/ it gives a response so how I can make my android app on physicsl device get a response from my localhost so I can work on data in my test.php file.

Comment: If your app crashes then you will find the cause and the exceptions in the logcat. You can then also catch those exceptions. Please post relevant part from the logcat.

Comment: `response comes from okhttp is null ` Which statement/variable exactly? Give some better info!